# Array does not update with useState hook and for loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update each element in an array using a for loop

When you click on the 'add all' button, it should start updating each element of the array

The update should happen one after the other, and should be visible in the UI

The array is stored in a `useState` hook

However, the array is not updating as expected

Here's the link to the CodeSandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-hooks-z3wq7?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState(() => fakeUsers);

  function addHandler(id){
      let arr = cloneDeep(users);
      let i = arr.findIndex((u) => u.id === id);
      arr[i].added = true;
      setUsers(arr);
  };

  async function addAll() {
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      let id = users[i].id;
      await delay(1000);
      addHandler(id);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addAll}>add all</button>
      {users.map((e) => (
        <div>
          {e.name}-{e.added ? "YES" : "NO"}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an out of date version of the user array.
when the second user is added it uses a reference of the array where none is added.

You can provide a update function to setState to always use the current reference:

```
setUsers(users => {
  let arr = cloneDeep(users);
  let i = arr.findIndex((u) => u.id === id);
  arr[i].added = true;
  return arr
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use spread operator instead of cloneDeep.

Also, not sure why you are setting the initial state using arrow function.

here's the updated code

```
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(fakeUsers);

  function addHandler(id) {
    let arr = [...users];
    let i = arr.findIndex((u) => u.id === id);
    arr[i].added = true;
    setUsers(arr);
  }

  async function addAll() {
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      let id = users[i].id;
      await delay(1000);
      addHandler(id);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addAll}>add all</button>
      {users.map((e) => (
        <div>
          {e.name}-{e.added ? "YES" : "NO"}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It works, but I heard spread operator does shallow copy, so didn't want to use it. Wouldn't `arr[i].added` perform the operation on the `users` instead of `arr`?

Comment: Don't mutate state directly.